# Laravel:how can I pass a variable from a controller to another?

Tags: php, variables, laravel, parameters, controller

I'm pretty new in programming (still a student) and really new in Laravel. I have to make an extranet for the firefighters so, mostly, the records I need from my DB are their personal data, their agenda, and stuff like that. Maybe I'm watching at this in a wrong way but I'd like to build my project in this way:

BaseController
The __constructor contains the logic to get the data I would need in every view. In fact I return all my variables with the 'View::share' code

```
View::share('milite', $milite);
View::share('agenda', $agenda);
View::share('log_accessi', $log_accessi);
View::share('data_import', $data_import);
```

Although I'd like to use another class, AgendaController (which would extend BaseController) to get data from the firefighters'agenda. In order to do that I'd need to pass the variable $milite from the BaseController to the AgendaController.

I really don't know how to do that! Could someone, please, explain me?
I hope you understand my problem as English is not my mother language. Thank you so much!

Sara

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to share variables across controllers:

1. If you share variables across views just like you did, simple use the variable $milite in other controllers. It should be just fine.
2. You may define a static variable in your base class so that the variable could be used among all classes that extend base class.
3. In the constructor of AgendaController, just pass firefighters'agenda as a paramter to construct the controller.
4. Simply call the method of firefighters'agenda in AgendaController by App::make(' firefighters'agenda')->with(your parameter). In this way, you may pass value and call methods of other controllers.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the correct way to do this. First of, having all kinds of logic in the constructor of BaseController will slow your application down eventually as all requests will have to go through these logic statements regardless if they need it or not. In fact controllers shouldn't be interacting with each other at all as what they should be doing is handling incoming HTTP requests and providing responses.

To give you an answer though, since you're extending BaseController anyway, at least move your logic out of the BaseController constructor and move it to a public method in BaseController

```
class BaseController extends Controller 
{


    public function fillView()
    {
         $data = array('someData' =>  'data');
         return $data;
    }
```

And then in your AgendaController you can access the public method by virtue of inheritance:

```
   <?php


   class AgendaController extends BaseController
   {

         public function showAgenda(){
              $dataFromBaseController = $this->fillView();
              ...
         }

   }
```

Again this isn't how you should do it. What you would normally do is to move the logic related stuff to methods in another class (say a service or may be a repository if you're accessing the DB) and then using laravel's dependency injection container to get access to those methods in your controller.